# Concurrent writes to different properties of GAE Datastore Entity

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, concurrentmodification

I'm using Google Appengine in Java flavor, and i'm trying to do the following:

1 - create an entity with property COUNT as 0.

2a - kick off a task queue task that does some network call, and updates a STATUS property for this same entity (using `Datastore#put`)

2b - meanwhile, in the original "thread", save a different number for COUNT. (also using `Datastore#put`)

given that `2a` and `2b` may finish in parallel at the exact same moment, but they update two different properties (`STATUS` and `COUNT`), would these ever conflict or throw like a concurrent modification exception?

Comment: Datastore puts whole entity at once, so without transactions last update will rewrite other field with an old value

Comment: @IgorArtamonov what about embedded entities? would those be able to update independently of the containing "parent" entity?

Answer (score 1):

As Igor Artamonov commented, changing just one property of an entity still requires re-writing the entire entity. With this in mind you're looking at 2 entity writes which would have to be done inside transactions to prevent overwriting each-other.

The flow you describe will cause transaction collisions if the transaction associated with the task enqueud in 2a starts before the 2b transaction is committed.

The 2a task execution is delayed - it'll be a request hitting you app at a later moment (the actual delay depending on your app's load at the moment and its scalability config). It can be *a lot* longer than the 2b execution. Or it could be tiny, allowing 2a to start before 2b ends.

I'd recommend changing the order of the ops to make it more predictable and, as a side effect, minimize the chances of transaction collisions/retries:

- on the current request thread perform 2b (in a transaction)
- in the same transaction [transactionally enqueue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#enqueuing_tasks_in_cloud_datastore_transactions) the 2a task, which should happen only after 2b is successful. Otherwise you need to take care of potentially enqueueing multiple 2a tasks during 2b retries.

Comment: so... with the `STATUS` property, i was really only hoping to make it where i mark something as failed, so that it gets picked up later (when the other dependent service is back up and running finally). should i actually just create a separate datastore entity for each failed task?

Comment: That works as well. Another possibility, at least in python, is to make the tasks re-queue themselves on failure (with a backoff delay) so that you don't need to also keep track of them in the datastore (as separate entities or as properties of the entities they operate on). But it's really up to you and your app, either way it's ok.

Comment: i do have a backoff already, and they claim their SLA is "24 hours". but i am just overly paranoid. this way it'll allow them well over a week if they need it.